# How does $\mathbb R \subseteq B(0,2)$ hold in the discrete metric?

Tags: general-topology

How is this hold that $\mathbb R \subseteq B(0,2)$ where 
$\big<\mathbb R,d\big>$ and d is a discrete metric?

By doing so we showed that $\mathbb R $ is bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mimicking my answer to your previous question:

Recall that
$$
B(0,2) = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid d(0,x)<2\}.
$$
If $d$ is the discrete metric, then
$$
d(0,x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=0$}\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ so that $d(0,x)<2$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $B(0,2)=\mathbb{R}$, so that $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded in the discrete metric.

Comment: Isn't it actually a subset of the ball?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan I'm assuming that your space if $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric, in which case we also have $B(0,2)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

let $x\in \mathbb R$. Then $d(x,0)=1$ if $x\neq 0$, and $d(x,0)=0$ otherwise. Hence $d(x,0)\leq 1 <2$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the definition of a ball.  $B(a,b)$ is all the points within a distance $b$ of $a$ with the given metric, that is $\{c|d(a,c) \lt b\}$.  What is the distance between $0$ and $1000$ in the discrete metric?  Hint:  it is not $1000$.

Comment: It is 1 since they are not equal

Comment: That is correct.  That means $1000 \in B(0,2)$.  And the rest of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: The rest of $\mathbb R $ is also in the ball

Comment: That is correct, which answers your question.  I often find it useful to think about a concrete example.